# Timeout during longer ASP.Net process

Tags: asp.net, timeout

We have an ASP.Net page with a button that kicks off a have a process that can take up to 3 minutes to complete.  The problem we are running into is that the connection between IE and IIS aborts before the process can complete.

We are looking at improving the performance of the task or moving the task into an asynchronous process but in the mean time I'm looking for a quick fix that would allow the task to complete.

I have...

- changed the executionTime in  to 300 seconds
- increased the connection timeout in IIS on the site to 300 seconds
- increased the Application Pool timeouts to 300 seconds

but I continue to see (Aborted) in the Result column of the Network monitor in IE after 90 seconds.

As a side note I should point out that the process does complete (I can see in the logs).  The user just doesn't know because IE is no longer connected.

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the below two things,

1. In Web.Config file,

   ```
   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="300"/>
   ```
2. In application pool’s worker process default idle timeout is also set to 300 seconds.

Comment: The session timeout is not a problem from what I can see.  We actually keep our sessions for quite awhile.  The default idle timeout is already set to 300.